# Samba Winbind on Centos 7 not reading full name for any AD user

Tags: linux, centos, samba, passwd

I have Samba configured to use winbind to authenticate users through our Active Directory domain controller. Everything seems to be working, it is reading uidNumber, gidNumber, unixHomeDirectory, and loginShell for each of the configured users. However, none of these users have a pw_gecos full name attribute in either getent passwd or wbinfo -i. Sample outputs shown:

```
getent passwd testuserad:
testuserad:*:23456:210001::/home/users/testuserad:/bin/sh

wbinfo -i testuserad:
testuserad:*:23456:210001::/home/users/testuserad:/bin/sh
```

Whereas a local user on the system looks like this:

`testuserlocal:x:87645:1100:Test User:/home/users/testuserlocal:/bin/bash`

Does anybody have any experience with this problem? I saw a few other threads with this issue online, but they were from around 8-10 years ago and I never really saw a solution for it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution on an archived email chain. The solution is to populate the gecos attribute in the domain with the same value that is set in displayName attribute. Immediately after setting it, the full name was present on the winbind client side.

Source: https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2020-February/228335.html